# NullPointerException with a Filechooser?

Tags: nullpointerexception, jfilechooser

My code looks good enough to me, but I keep getting a nullpointerexception. I'm inputting a text file that looks like this:

Kermit D.Frogge  17.25 5.25 0.0 8.0 1.5 8.0 2.25 7.75 0.0 8.0 2.0

This is some of my code:

```
private static BufferedReader br;
private static StringTokenizer strTkn;


private static String st, firstName, middleInitial, lastName;
private static double monRegHours, monOverHours, tuesRegHours, tuesOverHours,      wedRegHours, wedOverHours,
thurRegHours, thurOverHours, friRegHours, friOverHours;
private static double totalRegHours, totalOverHours, hourlyWage, regularPay, overtimePay, weeklyPay;
private static JFileChooser chooser;


public static void main (String args []) throws IOException 
{
chooser();
getData();
calcpay();
printresult();
}


public static void chooser() throws IOException
{
JFileChooser chooser=new  JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{
  File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
  br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
  st="";
  while((st=br.readLine())!=null);
  {
    System.out.println ("Data Line = " + st ); //print the whole line
  }
  }
  }


public static void getData() throws IOException
{
 strTkn = new StringTokenizer(st, " .");

 firstName = strTkn.nextToken();
 middleInitial = strTkn.nextToken();
 lastName = strTkn.nextToken();
 hourlyWage = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());

 monRegHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());
 monOverHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());

 tuesRegHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());
 tuesOverHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());

 wedRegHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());
 wedOverHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());

 thurRegHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());
 thurOverHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());

 friRegHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());
 friOverHours = Double.parseDouble(strTkn.nextToken());


}


public static void calcpay()
{
totalRegHours = monRegHours + tuesRegHours + wedRegHours + thurRegHours + friRegHours;
totalOverHours = monOverHours + tuesOverHours + wedOverHours + thurOverHours +    friOverHours;

overtimePay = round(totalOverHours * (1.5 * hourlyWage));
regularPay  = round(hourlyWage * totalRegHours);
weeklyPay = regularPay + overtimePay;
}


public static void printresult()
{
System.out.println("Name: " + firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName);
System.out.printf("Weekly Pay: " + "$%.2f\n", weeklyPay);
//this allows me to print $x.50 instead of $x.5, and not have repeating decimals
}


public static double round(double num) 
{
// rounding to two decimal places
num *= 100;
int rounded = (int) Math.round(num);
return rounded/100.0;
```

Sorry if it looks bad, my computer doesn't like to copy paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very simple error. You have placed a semicolon after your while loop.

```
while((st=br.readLine())!=null);
```

Remove the semi-colon and it will work fine.

Comment: Now it prints the data line fine, but still gives me a null pointer when I try to calculate and use the stringtokenizer...

Comment: you don't need a while loop at all. Just use st=br.readLine(); remove the while loop, and it would work fine. Your exit condition is that st=null, when the loop exits, so obviously it will give a null pointer exception.